# How do I safely upgrade xampp without losing database i have created?

Tags: mysql

Also when i try to upgrade the with older version being installed, i get this error that port is being used or similar sorts. Do I complete installation by uninstalling?

I am searching for complete answer just to be sure about upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to listen to the doctors' motto - "Do no harm".

Take a backup of your database before doing **anything** else - that way, if you make a mistake, you can always retrace your steps and you won't have lost any important (or even unimportant) data.

Comment: is taking backup meant, exporting all the database created and save it?

Comment: Use a tool such as mysqldump and backup all your data. That way, if you do make a mistake, you've lost nothing (but time!). There are other backup solutions, but this is the easiest and comes with MySQL anyway. You could use Percona's [XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup) if you need hot backups, or you could consider some of the solutions [here](http://www.noupe.com/development/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html).